# See Visual Studios actual Git commands

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Im using Visual Studio 2019, with new fancy Git experience. Is there any way to view the actual commands sent to git. Like a log file or perhaps even some documentation of exacly what is done

Comment: You can view history using reflog. Check out this SO answer - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7435555/5698740). Note: This will only show history where the HEAD was changed. But your question doesn't ask for that.

Comment: ok, kool, thanks! (add it answer if you want the creds)

Comment: Don't mind if I do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view history using [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

```
git reflog
```

Check out this SO answer too - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435452/history-or-log-of-commands-executed-in-git/7435555#7435555)

Note: Reflog only shows history whenever the HEAD changes. Meaning you won't see history for `git log` like commands.