# History of all git commands issued from repo's initialization

Tags: git

I have the following use case:

On my local computer, I had the following structure of files/folders outside of any version control system, including git.

```
ProjectFolder
    ---Folder1
        ----File1.txt
    ----Folder2
        ----File2.txt
        ----100s of other files/folders
```

In preparation for version control, I first ran `git init` in this folder.

This gave me:

```
ProjectFolder
    ---.git
    ---Folder1
        ----File1.txt
    ----Folder2
        ----File2.txt
        ----100s of other files/folders
```

I then went to github and created a repository, say:

`https://github.com/Tryer/ProjectFolder.git`

After this, from the command line on my machine, I issued:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/Tryer/ProjectFolder.git`

I did not want to add `Folder2` and its contents to the commit. I only wanted `Folder1` and its contents to be committed.

I, by mistake, did not created a proper `.gitignore` file leading to staging of some files from `Folder2` when I then issued `git add .`

I do not now remember exactly whether I issued `git rm -f <files from Folder2>` or `git rm --cached <files from Folder2>` to unstage the unneeded files from `Folder2`. The former would have forced deleted the files from `Folder2` from both the staging area as well as my working tree (something I did not intend/want). The latter would have only unstaged the files but left them in my working tree (something that is precisely what I would have wanted.)

The number of files under `Folder2` are rather large and a due diligence check on `Folder2`'s contents manually on my machine seems to reveal nothing amiss in terms of missing files from my working tree.

Yet, just to be absolutely sure, is there a way to list all of the git commands ever issued under a repository from the beginning of time? Note that I am not asking for a history of commands I have issued from the terminal command line. This would be available in a powershell history or bash shell history.

A previous question of exactly this issue is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435452/history-or-log-of-commands-executed-in-git). However, the question is about 10 years old and the highest voted answer there suggests to use `git reflog`. However, that seems to give history in terms of commits. I am looking more for the exact git commands that I have executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible with Git. Git does not keep track of the commands executed in a repository.

Your best bet is your shell's command history.

Comment: The most downvoted answer in the linked page does say something similar.

Comment: @phd I did. Seems like you have too. Got it up from -9 to a -7 now. :-)

Comment: Yep, that was me. :-)